# Increase width automatically by dragging of children but with scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/6/

The above link demonstrates my problem.

I want to increase the size of the `container` when trying to drag children out of it,  keeping the size of `parent` fixed & hence, a scroll should appear within `parent` with `overflow:scroll` for complete scrolling of `container`

The main intention is to increase the size of the canvas keeping the viewport size constant & hence, should have scrolls.

Have been struggling for 2 days but no luck.

Comment: `scrollTop` is useful, as it tells you how much a div has scrolled with vertical scrolling.  `$(this).css("height", $(this).height() + $(this).scrollTop());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the amount that you have dragged the element once it reaches the boundary, then on the "drag" event, increase the size of the container while dragging depending on the direction that you are going. X or Y.

Judson

Comment: yeah, I do that, please see the fiddle attached in the question.

Comment: Try adding an inner-container and increasing/ decreasing accordingly  the size of it as your drag with will increase/ descrease the scroll area. :) Essientailly you need some block element (hidden) inside the contianer to force the scroll area bigger.